# Google Contact Api pushing contact to https://contacts.google.com/other instead of https://contacts.google.com/ .

Tags: google-api, php-curl, google-contacts-api

I am working with Google Contact Api V.3 and able to push contacts to gmail through PHP Curl. But it is pushing contacts to https://contacts.google.com/other instead of 
https://contacts.google.com/. 
app is not verified yet. I thought, i will do it later. Can someone tell me why it is pushing contacts to "/other" URL instead of root?
TIA

Comment: Where's your code? What setups/configurations are you using (if any)?

Comment: I have created a project through gmail account and enabled Contact Api v.3, then following documentation provided redirect URL and got credentials  "google_client_id" , "google_client_secret"  after authorization with  OAuth 2.0 i was able to post contact successfully through PHP CURL but it pushed in other contacts. Here is the code. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/056e357180ac711d5f74c5e519520d50